# What is the best way to remove logs file Core Data creates, when removing a UIManagedDocument from iCloud?

Tags: core-data, icloud, nsfilemanager

I would have thought `NSFileManager`s method of `removeItemAtURL:error:` would remove the Core Data log files created when using UIManagedDocuments with iCloud.

What is the best way to make sure all of these log files are removed?

Answer (score 0):

I have used...

```
- (void)deleteRemnantsOfOldDatabaseDocumentAndItsTransactionLogsWithCompletionHandler:(completion_success_t)completionBlock
{    
    __weak CloudController *weakSelf = self;

    NSURL *databaseStoreFolder = self.iCloudDatabaseStoreFolderURL;
    NSURL *transactionLogFolder = self.transactionLogFilesFolderURL;

    [self deleteFileAtURL:databaseStoreFolder withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL docSuccess) {
        [weakSelf deleteFileAtURL:transactionLogFolder withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL logSuccess) {
            completionBlock(docSuccess && logSuccess);
        }];
    }];
}
```

In conjunction with...

```
- (void)deleteFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL withCompletionBlock:(completion_success_t)completionBlock
{    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
        NSError *coordinatorError = nil;
        __block BOOL success = NO;

        [fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:fileURL
                                            options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
                                              error:&coordinatorError
                                         byAccessor:^(NSURL *writingURL) {

                                             NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
                                             NSError *removalError = nil;
                                             if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[writingURL path]]) {
                                                 if (![fileManager removeItemAtURL:writingURL error:&removalError]) {
                                                     NSLog(@"deleteFileAtURL: removal error: %@", removalError);
                                                 } else {
                                                     success = YES;
                                                 }
                                             } 
                                         }];

        if (coordinatorError) {
            NSLog(@"deleteFileAtURL: coordinator error: %@", coordinatorError);
        }

        completionBlock(success);
    });
}
```

Note: this was used for a single document toolbox style app, and was intended more for clearing out the iCloud container before creating a brand new document, in an 'apparently' empty iCloud store for the first time.  But I'm sure it can be adapted without too much work.

Oops, the above won't make sense/work without:

```
typedef void (^completion_success_t)(BOOL success);
```

You can debug the contents of your iCloud container and verify things have been removed by using a method like (which to be honest I've probably lifted from somewhere else and modified):

```
- (void)logDirectoryHierarchyContentsForURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:url
                                                   includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey]
                                                                      options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                 errorHandler:nil];

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSURL *itemURL in directoryEnumerator) {
        NSString *fileName;
        [itemURL getResourceValue:&fileName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:NULL];

        NSDate *modificationDate;
        [itemURL getResourceValue:&modificationDate forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:NULL];

        [results addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", itemURL, modificationDate]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Directory contents: %@", results);
}
```

And it's also worth logging onto [developer.icloud.com](http://developer.icloud.com) and examining what is actually in the iCloud store.  There is sometimes a difference between what is retained in the device ubiquity container, and what is actually in the iCloud server folder structure.  Between all of these you can get quite a good idea of what's going on.