# How to delete data in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, nspersistentstore

I've been working to migrate an iCloud store to local storage in the application sandbox.  The code looks like this (error handling code has been removed for clarity):

```
NSPersistentStore *iCloudStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:legacyStoreUrl options:options error:&error];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *targetStoreUrl = [self localStorageUrl];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                       nil];

[_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:legacyStore toURL:targetStoreUrl options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:nil];
```

At this point we have successfully migrated the iCloud store to the new location in the application sandbox, but there is still data in iCloud and the old sqlite file in place... the following line deletes the sqlite file

```
[fileManager removeItemAtURL:legacyStoreUrl error:nil]
```

So after running all of this my file system and persistent stores are looking good as far as I can tell.  The one missing bit is that the data that stored in iCloud is not deleted from iCloud (though it is no longer accessed by the app).  What else needs to happen to programmatically delete the iCloud data?  The apple iCloud docs mention deleting the transaction logs but I do not see any other files in my Documents folder that need cleaning up.  Any help is much appreciated!

Update:

The iCloud store was originally set up using the following options:

```
NSURL *ubiquityContainerUrl = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSString* coreDataCloudContent = [[ubiquityContainerUrl path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data"];



NSURL *coreDataUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:coreDataCloudContent];

options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
               @"MyAppName.store", NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,
               coreDataUrl, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey,
               nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction log folder will be at whatever location you set `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey` to when you created the store in iCloud, and *may* be outside your Documents folder if that's where you chose to put it.

Log onto [developer.icloud.com](http://developer.icloud.com) and see if anything has been stored at that point.

To delete, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622887/1320544) for something I've used in the past:

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I added an update above that includes the code  that originally set up the iCloud container.  Unfortunately, when I download the app data off of the device using Xcode organizer and search for "MyAppName.store" or "data" it finds nothing - but the data remains in iCloud.

Comment: I doubt you'll see the iCloud stuff by downloading the app data through Xcode Organiser... The iCloud ubiquity folder for your app is held in a different part of the filesystem. To get it, log on to developer.icloud.com, or look in the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` folder on a Mac that is logged into the same iCloud store. The URL you get back from calling `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` gives you the root location of the ubiquity folder on the local device - pass that URL to the logging method I gave in my other answer to get a debug dump of everything in iCloud.

Comment: Looking at your code above, your log files will be in the `coreDataUrl` folder, which should resolve to `/data` within your iCloud folder - this sits at the same level as `/Documents`, which is why you can't see it *in* Documents.  So to delete them, pass `coreDataUrl` to a suitable delete function.

Answer (score 6):

I just discovered that Xcode allows you to reset the container using Xcode menu:

```
Debug->iCloud->Delete Container Contents
```

It is also helpful to be able to see the content online: https://developer.icloud.com/