# Deleting iCloud container contents

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm trying to reset/empty my iCloud container for development purposes.
I've tried Xcode > Debug > iCloud > Delete Container contents, but it has no effect. I still see previously saved data appearing in new instances of my app.

Previous documentation suggests checking the data on developer.icloud.com, but this seems to have been moved by Apple, and now shows a page referencing CloudKit.

How do I view/delete what's in my iCloud container? I'd like to simply delete the Core Data SQLite store I have in there, so I can start over.

Answer (score 4):

Log in to the cloudkit dashboard. Click on Deployment near the bottom left side. An option will appear to Reset Development Environment.

Comment: I just tried this. In production the option wasn't there, in dev, I tried it to no effect. If I launch my app it still gets iCloud data. Is CloudKit dashboard the place to be doing this?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you had deployed. The docs say it only works if it has never been deployed;  " If you have never deployed your development environment, resetting the development environment deletes all the records and record types. "

Comment: I haven't deployed anything - not using CloudKit at all. I'd simply like to reset my personal iCloud sync data (i.e. Core Data database) on my device for development purposes. It keeps syncing my old data back. :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I see others have come across it as well; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402186/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-logs-file-core-data-creates-when-removing-a-uima/16622887#16622887